# Sorting dataframe by two columns when one is selected by user

Tags: r, sorting, shiny

I want to sort data frame by two columns first is factor and second numeric but this is selected in shiny.

When I use this line with specified columns it works well.

```
 iris1<-iris[with(iris,order(Species,Sepal.Length,decreasing = T)), ]
```

But inside shiny I replace Sepal.Length with reactive values and this returns error. Please see MRE

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)


shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Miles Per Gallon"),

  sidebarPanel(selectInput("a","select column",c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"))),

  mainPanel(tableOutput("b"))
))

# server.R   
library(shiny)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  col<-reactive({input$a})
 output$b<- renderTable({
########### this line probably causes the problem
   iris1<-iris[with(iris,order(Species,col(),decreasing = T)), ]
})
})
```

Error I get is

```
Error in order(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  argument lengths differ
```

Comment: Which column col() refer to when no col are selected by user ?

Comment: Sepal.Length is there as a default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using `get()` to convert string to column name:

```
col <- "Sepal.Width"
iris[with(iris, order(Species, get(col), decreasing = TRUE)), ]
```

And within shiny it should be: `get(col())`.

Note that `input$a` is already reactive, so we can say: `get(input$a)`

Comment: excellent I thought that it could be problem Species without quotes and reactive value with quotes but did not know where to go from there :)

Comment: @TomasH `col()` is a function in base R, I would avoid using existing function names as variables.